# can i convert from char* to UChar in ICU?

Tags: c++, icu

I have a char * (containing utf-8 string) that i want to pass to ICU to convert it to ANSI (ISO-8859-6) . Unfortunately it seems that most ICU functions take UChar not char*.

**How can I make this conversion?**

Comment: "containing Unicode character" = UTF-8?

Comment: `char*` as a type gives no indication of the underlying encoding; the *encoding* is the important part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you look at the docs? [`UnicodeString::fromUTF8`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classUnicodeString.html#a33ef2891f0ace7930dff3a34778bf4f7) stands out...

```
// given char* str
UnicodeString ustr = UnicodeString::fromUTF8(StringPiece(str));
```

I assume you know how to then convert `ustr` to the desired codepage using [`UnicodeString::extract`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classUnicodeString.html#ac15fabe40a5101c6419492dc751da345).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the static member function `FromUTF8` to convert a UTF-8 `StringPiece` to a `UnicodeString`. So, if you have a char*, you can convert it like this:

```
const char* str;
size_t len;
UnicodeString ucs = UnicodeString::FromUTF8(StringPiece(str, len));
```